# UIImageView tap to zoom in witout UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I build a app with UIImageView and I searched the net but could not find a complete solution without a UIScrollView to do tap zoom in my view.

This is what I have now ,but it does not work well:

It is possible ? If there is a better way to do it I would love for you to help me.

in viewDidLoad :

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[imageViewForCrop addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

My handle Double Tap method :

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

CGPoint tappedPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGFloat xCoordinate = tappedPoint.x;
CGFloat yCoordinate = tappedPoint.y;



   // zoom in
[imageViewForCrop setFrame:CGRectMake( imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.x , imageViewForCrop.frame.origin.y  , imageViewForCrop.frame.size.width +200, imageViewForCrop.frame.size.height+200)];

imageViewForCrop.center = CGPointMake(xCoordinate , yCoordinate);
```

}

Comment: Do you want to zoom to see more detail of the image or just make it larger?

Comment: just make it larger where the user tap.

Comment: Do you want to zoom at the point that the user tap on or just make it bigger no matter how?

Comment: want to zoom at the point that the user tap.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a transform.  This will make the image view twice the size of the original.

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    imageViewForCrop.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
}
```

Comment: It works well,  How do I get to the image where I pressed of the screen? because now the image grow without save by the center of tap.

Comment: The image is contained inside the `UIImageView`.  However, the image did not change.  Are you wanting to save the transformed image?